# Zend Server can't connect to mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, zend-server

I've installed Zend Server CE on Windows 7 and I can't connect to MySQL.

When I try to log into phpMyAdmin I get the following error

```
#2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server
```

When I try to connect through a test PHP script like so...

```
$db = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1:3306", "user", "pass"); if (!$db) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); } echo 'Connected successfully<br><br>';
```

I get

```
Could not connect: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

When I log into Zend Server Admin, the mysql extension is turned on. But when I look at what ports are open via the cmd command 'netstat -ano'. It doesn't show anything listening on 3306.

I found a similar question here [connecing to mysql with Zend Server CE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747376/connecing-to-mysql-with-zend-server-ce) that points to an answer here http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=21873 but it doesn't work for me.

I'm don't have a my.ini file in my mysql 5.1 folder. I have the following files:

my-huge.ini

my-innodb-heavy-4G.ini

my-large.ini

my-medium.ini

my-small.ini

my-template.ini

None of them have the mentioned lined for me to comment out.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it means that the machine exists and host name is ok. but that it has no services listening on the given port.

Might be firewall there is  blocking you.

Comment: It's running on my personal pc. I don't think it's a firewall problem.

Comment: I had to uninstall Zend Server and then reinstall it. I think something went wrong during the process.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the MySQL server is not running. Open the Services with `ApacheXX-Zend`, and start the `MYSQL_ZendServerXX` (Status = Started).

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a previous mysql instance installed?? Zend Server CE comes with it's own MySQL instance and it is possible that you (or your SO) have to stop the previous mysql installation in order to function properly.

Comment: I did. I downloaded the mysql installer and then used it to uninstall mysql. That cleared up some of the problems, but I ran into some others, so I cleared out zend server completely and went with WAMP.